# Unset specific value of header in the apache

Tags: apache-httpd

My curl showing me header:

```
Vary: X-Forwarded-For,User-agent,Accept-Encoding
```

I want to remove the value "X-Forwarded-For".

The option in apache "Header unset Vary" remove my Vary header with all values.
How can I unset only one value for my specific header?
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no experience with that, but You should check [mod_header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) fo edit option
I'd try this:

```
Header edit Vary "X-Forwarded-For" ""
```